# How to accept the answers

Tags: support

I want to know how to accept the answers when I got satisfactory answer and make the question answered??

This information is provided in faq.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask):

> When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.
>
> [accept an answer http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png)
>
> This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (And if you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)